# Form handling using cache-and-network policy, how can I handle this case?

Tags: javascript, forms, svelte, urql

I'm using [urql](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql/) and [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/) for a new web app.

I ran into a logical problem that I can't figure out how to best solve.

Suppose I have many todos and the list of these todos is already cached on my phone browser.

While I'm on the subway (very slow network) I open one to edit it (then the app loads the edit form with the todo from the cache) but since I use the "`cache-and-network`" policy and shortly before my wife changed it the todo re-updates itself undoing all my changes that I was writing in the textarea.

How do you think this situation can be fixed?

1. Should I wait for the `cache-and-network` to finish before I can edit the form? (This is not great for a maybe-offline UX);
2. should I warn the user that there is an updated todo?
3. should I warn the user that there is an updated todo only when I'm saving it in the DB in the backend?
4. other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `navigator.onLine` to check if your user is online or offline. if he is offline, save his changes to `localStorage`. when the status changes again; you can compare your current state to `localStorage` and update the form accordingly.

most of the logic I'm talking about is explained [here](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/graphcache/offline/)

if you need help with saving a form in `localStorage`, you can use this template:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelector('#form-id').elements, function(el) {
  localStorage.setItem(el.name, el.value);
});

// then refresh the page and run this to restore your form values:
[].forEach.call(document.querySelector('#form-id').elements, function(el) {
  el.value = localStorage.getItem(el.name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You describe a classic `race condition` where 2 users create a different operation over the same resource (in our use-case - a record in db)

**Short answer:** `record versioning` - manage a unique version number for each record. changes can only be executed when deliver with the same version value

**Long answer:** Suppose we are using a `no-sql db` where every list is saved in `lists` collection where every record looks something like this:

```
{
  id: 'uuid-4',
  items: [
    { name: 'item #1', checked: false },
    { name: 'item #2', checked: true },
    { name: 'item #3', checked: false }
  ],
  version: 1648727895753
}
```

In the example above, I've use a `timestamp` as a record version (using the `new Date().getTime()` method). Every time this record is updated - the version changes as well.

Now - let's describe your scenario again:

2 users downloading the same `todo list` from server. At this point in time - both users have the same version value (let's say, version `A`). Now, let's assume that one user made an update while the other user is offline (in your example - due to traveling). In order for this pattern to work, we change the version value after each successful update so now the record has a new version value (let's say, version `B`). When the other user will try to make a change -  it will be blocked because he still got the old version number (in our example `A`). In order to make a change - the newest version (`B`) should be downloaded first, then the user will update his own edits and write his changes to db (this process will result with an updated record with version `C`)

So in order to make this work, one should create the following mechanism:

Server Side (db logic)

- on record update

  - make update only if request version value equals to record version value
- on fetch record

  - return record with current version value

Client side (app logic)

- on app load

  - fetch current todo list record (by `id` field)
- on record update

  - send update to server with current version value
  - if update fails:

    - save current todo list record as `old version`
    - fetch current todo list record (by `id` field)
    - merge changes (you will decide how to reflect it to user)
    - send update to server with current version value (it's now the most updated one)

**Technical Notes**

- Merging between 2 record versions (e.g. - between to JSON-based object) is a whole universe by its own. You may use a 3rd-party library to spot the differences (such as [json-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-diff)) or decide to apply a default behavior (for instance: if an item from list was deleted in db it will have a different style apply so the user understand that this item was removed)
- Even now we still risk to have a race condition (well.. highly unlikely when using a simple `todo list` but may occur in application with high loads). For production ready setup - please consider using a message queue in order to apply all actions by a specific order (first in first out). Again - it's an overkill to your use-case but since we are solving here a more general problem - I think it's worth mentioning

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain/link me more about message queues?

Comment: sure thing! a general background can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern. A more specific documentation using `nats.io` as a pub sub solution (open source, free) https://docs.nats.io/nats-concepts/core-nats/pubsub